# MPMediaQuery: find Umlauts and special characters when searching

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, mpmediaquery

I'm using an `MPMediaQuery` to search for song titles in the user's library:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *titlePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:titleString
                                                                            forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle
                                                                         comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query addFilterPredicate: titlePredicate];


NSArray* result = query.items;
```

The `titleString` is an `NSString` that has been entered by the user and is taken from a `UISearchField`. This works fine in most cases, but fails in some: when you use iTunes on the desktop, you can search for 'holle' and it will find 'Der Hölle Rache'. This doesn't work with my approach. The same thing, searching for 'que' will not find 'Qué pasa?'. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`MPMediaPropertyPredicate` does not currently allow you to specify any `NSStringCompareOptions`. This situation would need a diacritic insensitive search, which would ignore any accents or other diacritic marks.

One workaround (although slower than ideal depending on library size) would be to iterate through the entire media library using a diacritic and case insensitive search using the `NSString` `rangeOfString:options:` method:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSArray *result = query.items;
NSString *searchString = @"que";

NSIndexSet *filteredSet = [result indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                                                  passingTest:^BOOL(MPMediaItem *song, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSRange foundRange = [songTitle rangeOfString:searchString
                                          options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    // rangeOfString:options: returns {NSNotFound, 0} if "que" is not found during search.
    if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound) { 
        return YES;
    } else
        return NO; 
}];

NSArray *filteredResult = [result objectsAtIndexes:filteredSet];
```

Comment: While I'm pretty sure that this will work, it's going to be unusably slow, because we'd have to loop over the whole database of songs. When the user enters something into a search field, every letter would be painfully slow (especially the first one).

Comment: Have you looked into using Core Data? It's optimized for fast "search as you type" searching and you could easily add a diacritic and case-insensitive predicate along with your search.

Comment: Yep, loading the search table into memory is certainly the way to go, but it's not a very simple task, because you then have to keep it up-to-date with the media library when it changes. I'm gonna write that up some time in the future, when I do, I'll post it here on SO.